# Is there a way to import PGP keys *interactively* using GPG?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I'm using PGP since version 2.3a, and I had liked the interactive user interface of it.
Specifically when opening a file with PGP keys, PGP asked me what I want to do with it, allowing me to confirm each single key found.

GPG however is completely different there:
When using key import, all keys from a file are imported without further questions.

Browsing the manual page I found no option to enable some interactive mode, so I'm asking:

Isn't here a way to let me confirm each key before importing using GPG?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sq keyring split` so that you have one key per file.

```
sq keyring split foo.gpg
for key in output-*; do
    gpg --show-keys "$key"
    if read -p "Import? " && [[ $REPLY = [Yy]* ]]; then
        gpg --import "$key"
    fi
    rm -v "$key"
done
```

Comment: What is `sq`? My system (OpenSUSE Leap 15.4) suggests: "ispell [ path: /usr/bin/sq, repository: zypp (repo-oss) ]"

Comment: It's "sequoia" (another OpenPGP toolkit). I don't think GnuPG CLI tools have an equivalent operation built in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems GnuPG cannot do that, because the main author thinks such a feature is not needed.

See [Allow "interactive" import of keys](https://dev.gnupg.org/T6366).